# freeswitch recordings during IVR

Tags: freeswitch

in last version of freeswitch i got a problem - on stereo records during ivr some noice presnt in b-channel.  dialplan:

```
<extension name="91:1">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^1203$" require-nested="false">
        <action application="export" data="dialed_extension=1203"/>
        <action application="set" data="hangup_after_bridge=false"/>
        <action application="set" data="session_in_hangup_hook=true"/>
        <action application="set" data="RECORD_STEREO=true"/>
        <action application="set" data="record_name=$${recordings_dir_tmp}/${strftime(%Y-%m-%d)}/${caller_id_number}.${dialed_extension}.${call_uuid}.wav" />
        <action application="record_session" data="${record_name}"/>
        <action application="set" data="execute_on_answer=python detect_gp ${record_name}"/>
        <action application="set" data="ivr_menu_terminator=*"/>
        <action application="ivr" data="91:1"/>
        <action application="playback" data="/etc/freeswitch/moh/moh" />
        <action application="hangup"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

[wav file left channel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyutqmse1pqn35p/example_left_ch.wav?dl=0)

how i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Sound like packet loss rather than noise.  Do recordings work in other call phases?  How is you system I/O during the IVR playback?

Comment: yes, recoding work after IVR and sound is fine. disk use max 4%

Answer (score 0):

Receiving out of band DTMF (RFC2833 telephone event 101) can interfere with recording.  You will get silent spots instead of tones.  That might explain why your recording sounds like the audio cuts out or packet loss.

Comment: RFC2833 telephone event receiving after recording announcment. on img 11:18:04 - 11:18:09 side-B play announcment and writes with silent spots [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwjo6436eacum9l/2017-11-22_141424.png?dl=0)